# How to use {cli} to format function name with a `.` properly?

Tags: r

If I have a regular function name, this works fine:

```r
fn_name <- "foo"

cli::cli_li("My fuction is {.fn {fn_name}}")
#> • My fuction is `foo()`
```

But, if I have a function name with a `.` as a prefix, this produces undesired output:

```r
cli::cli_li("My fuction is {.fn .{fn_name}}")
#> • My fuction is `` .`foo()` ()``
```

Desired output:

```r
#> • My fuction is `.foo()`
```

**EDIT**:

The more general problem I am trying to solve is to produce the following message:

```r
fn_name <- "foo"

cli::cli_li("Fuction name changed from {.fn {fn_name}} to {.fn .{fn_name}}")
#> • Fuction name changed from `foo()` to `` .`foo()` ()``
```

Desired output:

```r
#> • Fuction name changed from `foo()` to `.foo()`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste0` you could do:

```r
fn_name <- "foo"
cli::cli_li("Fuction name changed from {.fn {fn_name}} to {.fn {paste0('.', fn_name)}}")
#> • Fuction name changed from `foo()` to `.foo()`
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the real function name as the function name?

```
fn_name <- ".foo"
cli::cli_li("My function is {.fn {fn_name}}")
#> • My function is `.foo()`
```

Comment: This can work, of course. I was looking for a more general solution because what I am actually trying to do is to create a list item that says (e.g.) ``"The name of function `foo()` was changed to `.foo()`"``. That's why I want to dynamically generate both of these variants from the same underlying function name. But, if that's not possible, I can of course just use the solution you provided and pass to separate patterns for `foo` and for `.foo()`.

Comment: It is possible, just assign them to variables, and then refer to the variables in the cli template. Currently you cannot mix literals and `{}` substitution within a `{.}` block. This is a cli bug: https://github.com/r-lib/cli/issues/474